# Spring integration mail inbound channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

i'm new to Spring and Spring integration, and i have a simple task to accomplish. Filtering some emails by it's subject though a regex and register some info in the db.

I've set the JavaMailProperties and the test gives me the output of the read emails but the method i'm setting with `service-activator` is never called and this is actually making me have a strong headache.

The following is the xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail  
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">  
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">pop3</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    </util:properties>
    <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3Adapter" 
                                      store-uri="pop3://username:password@mail..example.com:110/INBOX"                                     
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                          
                                      should-delete-messages="false"                                   
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                                      mail-filter-expression="subject matches '(^Presente+\\s([1-9]{1})+(\\s[-]\\s)+([A-Z]{4,})+(\\s[A-Z]{6,})$)'">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-delay="10000"/>
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">        
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="leggiMail" method="processa_mail"/>
    <bean id="leggiMail" class="it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.LeggiMail">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The `LeggiMail` class with the `processa_mail` method is very simple:

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class LeggiMail {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LeggiMail.class);
    public static int count_get = 0;
    @ServiceActivator
    public void processa_mail(MimeMessage mimeMessage) {
        count_get++;
        logger.debug("porcessa_mail working");
    }
```

The test class i'm using this application in:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/test-spring-configuration.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class LeggiMailTest {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LeggiMailTest.class);
    @Autowired
    LeggiMail lm;
    @Test
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void test_processa_mail(){
        logger.debug("Test started");
    }
}
```

The log `Test started` appears correctly in the console, but the log `porcessa_mail working` never shows up..

The first tutorial i found on this subject just spoke about a method that would have been called by default by the context. http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/read-emails-from-imap-with-spring.html (And it says that the method "processa_mail" should be called by default when the context is loaded, cause it's a `service-activator`.

Reading this tutorial about service activator didn't help enough: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html

Comment: And why should it be called. The application starts and stops after that if I'm correct. Also I wonder why are you loading 2 contexts and making it worse you are mixing 2 beans from different contexts... At first sight I would say your test is flawed.

Comment: Well according to this(http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/read-emails-from-imap-with-spring.html) tutorial the method should be called by default. I don't really understand why, but however, may i ask you a solution to call the method "after" reading the emails?

Comment: I simply cannot understand the procedure "in between"..

Comment: As I stated your test is flawed. You are loading 2 contexts, mixing beans from different contexts.... First fix your test, from what I see you are trying to do too much and work around the framework instead of working with the framework. Also the contexts loads and does nothing, you do a test but no mail will be checked because the context directly shuts down/gets cleaned. Or maybe even worse (I suspect) due to the double context you also have multiple channels.

Comment: OK, i took off the second context call. The context is loading anyway and the emails in the inbox are read. But the method is not called anyway.

Comment: Show your current Test class anyway. Seems for me you should wait some time in the end of test, because the `<poller>` uses separate thread to receive emails. But your main thread may not wait some time to allow to `LeggiMail` do the stuff.

Comment: @Artem Bilan You're right.. I've set the Thread to sleep for a wile and the method was run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to test some `async` stuff you some `barrier` to prevent the `main` thread to be stopped early, than it is neccessary for entire test-case.

The simples way is add `Thread.sleep()` before the end of test method.

But better solution is based on some `synchonizer`, like `CountDonwLatch`.

From other side there is `QueueChannel` in the Spring Integration. You can use it as an `output-channel` for `<service-activator>`. Inject it to the test class and wait on the `output.receive(10000)`. And `assert...` the result message to make your test realy unit-test.